# Database migration fail after adding indents with Kotlin multiline string and Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this definition

```
@Entity
class Call(@PrimaryKey val number: String)

@DatabaseView(
    """
            SELECT call.number AS callNumber FROM call
            """
)
data class UnknownCall(
    val callNumber: String
)
```

And I generate the Room schema, which corresponds to:

```
{
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "database": {
    "version": 2,
    "identityHash": "e64fd3352f3bec16e1caa3c70edf3793",
    "entities": [
      {
        "tableName": "Call",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`number` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`number`))",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "number",
            "columnName": "number",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": true
          }
        ],
        "primaryKey": {
          "columnNames": [
            "number"
          ],
          "autoGenerate": false
        },
        "indices": [],
        "foreignKeys": []
      }
    ],
    "views": [
  {
    "viewName": "UnknownCall",
    "createSql": "CREATE VIEW `${VIEW_NAME}` AS SELECT call.number AS callNumber FROM call"
  }
],
    "setupQueries": [
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)",
      "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, 'e64fd3352f3bec16e1caa3c70edf3793')"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I do some multiline indents on the view like:

```
@DatabaseView(
    """
            SELECT call.number AS callNumber 
            FROM call
            """
)
data class UnknownCall(
    val callNumber: String
)
```

The generated schema for that view changes to:

```
"views": [
      {
        "viewName": "UnknownCall",
        "createSql": "CREATE VIEW `${VIEW_NAME}` AS SELECT call.number AS callNumber \n            FROM call"
      }
    ],
```

And that causes an exception checking migrations, *just because I added some spaces* in the SQL query.

I dont understand what is happening here, I had to add a migration that drops my view and recreate it with the correct `\n` and spaces from the schema but I dont get why I need to do this since the data havent changed so it feels like a "hack".

What is happening?

Comment: Hi, If my answer helped you please accept it as an answer so it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this is the cost for Room automagically doing stuff for you.
Room does not really compare each schema element to determine if there are any changes to the schema.
Instead, Room Persistence Library generates unique `identity_hash` for every version of the database. And it is stored at `room_master_table.`

If I'm not mistaken it will ignore white spaces but since `\n` is a real character it will generate a new `identity_hash` and will result in the problem you have now.

You can see the hash values in the `room_master_table` on your device SQLite DB.